# How to replace last character of the string using c#?

Tags: c#

```
string str = "Student_123_";
```

I need to replace the last character "_" with ",". I did it like this.

```
str.Remove(str.Length -1, 1);
str = str + ",";
```

However, is it possible to achieve it more efficiently. may be one line of code.??
BTW, last character can be any character. So Replace wont work here.

Comment: Don't forget about StringBuilder. That contains several useful things to do with Strings, very efficiently. See my answer below.

Comment: One line of code does not always mean it's efficient.

Comment: Do you want an efficient way to do it, or a short way (as in fewer lines of code) to do it?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

No.

In C# strings are immutable and thus you can not change the string "in-place". You must first remove a part of the string and then create a new string. In fact, this is also means your original code is wrong, since `str.Remove(str.Length -1, 1);` doesn't change str at all, it returns a new string! This should do:

```
str = str.Remove(str.Length -1, 1) + ",";
```

Comment: I am roaming and seen this answer and wondering why count "1" is added? why not simply str.Remove(str.Length -1) to remove last char?

Comment: @A.T. I'm not too familiar with C#'s standard library, but looking at the documentation it seems that should work.

Answer (score 35):

C# .NET makes it almost too easy.

```
str = str.TrimEnd('_')
```

Comment: It should be noted that this will only work when there's a *single* underscore at the end of the string, as `TrimEnd` will remove **all** occurrences of the character specified.

Comment: @Ohad Schneider:  Not true - any number of the specified character will be trimmed off *either* end.  But I notice I didn't answer the OP's question because I didn't see the comma he was trying to add.  Therefore, I would edit my answer as: str = str.Trim('_') + ",";

Comment: `TrimEnd` will only remove *trailing* characters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Your answer will not work for other characters and/or if there are multiple trailing _

Answer (score 8):

Elegant but not very efficient.
Replaces any character at the end of str with a comma.

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, ".$", ",");
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the StringBuilder class

```
StringBuilder mbuilder = new StringBuilder("Student_123_");
mbuilder[mbuilder.Length-1] = ',';
Console.WriteLine(mbuilder.ToString());
```

Answer (score 7):

That's a limitation of working with `string`. You can use `StringBuilder` if you need to do a lot of changes like this. But it's not worth it for the simple task you need.

```
str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1) + ",";
```

Answer (score 2):

`str = str.Substring(0, str.Length-1) + ",";`

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you have won't work because `str.Remove(...)` doesn't manipulate `str`, it returns a new string with the removal operation completed on it.

So - you need:

```
str = str.Remove(str.Length-1,1);
str = str + ",";
```

In terms of efficiency, there are several other choices you could make (substring, trim ...) but ultimately you're going to get the same time/space complexity.

EDIT:

Also, don't try to squash everything into one line, the programmers who come after you will appreciate the greater readability. (Although in this case a single line is just as easy to read.) One line != more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

With one line of code you could write:

```
str = str.Remove(str.Length - 1, 1) + ",";
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.Remove` doesn't modify `str`, it returns a new string. Your first line should read `str = str.Remove...`

One line? OK: `str = str.Remove(str.Length - 1) + ",";`

I think that's as efficient as you're going to get. Technically, you are creating two new strings here, not one (The result of the Remove, and the result of the Concatenation). However, everything I can think of to not create two strings, ends up creating more than 1 other object to do so. You could use a StringBuilder, but that's heavier weight than an extra string, or perhaps a `char[]`, but it's still an extra object, no better than what I have listed above.

Answer (score 0):

```
// As string is array of chars you can use efficient "range" operator introduced in c# 8.0
string str = "Student_123_";
str = str[0..^1] + ",";
```

Comment: This doesn't replace anything

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my bad. Answer has been edited.